# Einstein bot: Can't use the Answer field value from Knowledge Object

Tags: knowledge, einstein, einstein-bots

Does anyone know why I can't use the Answer field from the Knowledge Object? When I try to add it, it gives a strange error:
Custom Field Definition ID: bad value for restricted picklist field: Knowledge__kav.Answer__c
[image: Einstein Bot: Knowledge Answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't select Answer__c field is due to  field type, which is rich text. Bot messages do not support all of the rich text features, nor do they support the maximum message length that rich text can support. For these reasons, object search does not allow you to save field configurations with rich text fields.

You do have a few alternatives that can satisfy a similar use case:

1. Use a normal text field on the bot, and implement automation to translate the Answer__c field values

- For instance, you can select the standard Summary field, since it's a normal text field with a low character count cap
- Using automation such as Apex, Lightning Flows, and/or Process Builder, you can design a process that will write compatible characters from Answer__c to Summary, with some limitations such as length.

2. Use a custom LWC for BaseChatMessage

- the BaseChatMessage LWC can be programmed to support many of the same features of rich text, such as inline images, links, and special formatting
- It can even go beyond the standard rich text editing and support inline files, video playback, and accordion menus, to describe a few possible implementations
- More information is available [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightningsnapin-base-chat-message/documentation):

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error text does not explain this.